# Getting 400 while connnecting to Azure managed Elastic search cloud

Tags: java, azure, elasticsearch

I deployed [Azure's Elastic Search managed solution](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/apps/elastic.ec-azure-pp). Now I am trying to connect to it from my local machine, using Java client version 8.2.3 (tried with 8.3 as well). Below mentioned is the endpoint and ports. However, I am getting 400 response code all the times.

Endpoint : https://2029sn39n2424brUem8868ae.es.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com (Sample only)
Port : 9200, 9300, 9243

- I tried adding/removing [IP filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-traffic-filtering-ip.html). Didn't work.
- I created API key and added it in request header. Didn't work.

Error response : `host= https://2029sn39n2424brUem8868ae.es.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com response=HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`

- [Authentication mechanism](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/8.3/_basic_authentication.html)
- [Doc insert mechanism](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing.html)
- Elastic search version is 8.3 (Azure managed).

Can anyone please help?

Comment: one imp thing, is that your java client and Elasticsearch server version needs to be same , so in your case you should use the `8.3` java client

Comment: @Amit Thank you for response. I checked this with 8.3 as well. Issue is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. The endpoint and port were incorrect.

Correct endpoint : {cluster_name}.es.{region_name}.azure.elastic-cloud.com
ex : `test_cluster.es.eastus.azure.elastic-cloud.com`
Correct port : 9243

Also, in RestClient builder constructor had to specify the protocol as `https`.

`RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, "https"));`

For anyone doing the same thing, wrote the exact steps here : https://medium.com/@udit.jindal/connecting-local-java-client-with-elastic-cloud-elasticsearch-on-cloud-on-azure-aws-c4b48b61a4cc

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify a little bit more your answer, the host should be just the hostname without "http" or "https" at the beginning. That worked for me.